# How do I convert a php web application into a desktop application and retain database

Tags: php, mysql, sqlite, web-applications, desktop-application

We have a web-application developed in PHP. But most of clients don't have internet connection all the time. So, is there way to convert the app into a desktop application so that it works stand alone and it syncs to web application whenever there is an internet connection? Currently I am testing it locally via xampp and it works but I dont want to have to install xampp or wamp on a clients pc. I am an amateur at coding FYI. I would appreciate any precise answer with example.

Comment: I am using this for some of my projects. https://github.com/cztomczak/phpdesktop

Comment: Hi Mark, is there any documentation for this?

Comment: follow the link and read through, you get everything you need there, simple paste your php code over. no installation needed and portable. but that part syncs to web application, I don;t really get you, but as long you are talking browser - web application, this will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid installing server on every client pc you can use **Virtual Machine**, so you would have same environment and just copy to every pc you need.

To keep the source code up to date (when connected) use GIT or other version control system (SVN may be easier to get into).

Comment: It seems a good option. Problem is I have no knowledge of virtual machines and how they work. I will learn this.

Answer (score 2):

A nice and simple way to do that without having to go through `XAMPP` or `LAMP` installation making it really simple to your users is to use PHP built-in server as of **PHP 5.4.0**.

```
$ cd ~/public_html
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

You can test this by adding an `index.php` in the `public_html` directory and then just run the command `$ php -S localhost:8000` **inside** `public_html`. Open up your browser and type `localhost:8000` so you can see your `index.php` file.

Another important thing is that your users must have `Mysql` installed (or whatever `DBMS` you are currently using).

Source [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php)

Comment: Impressive. I am going to test this to see how it works then get back

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `mysql` or whatever `DBMS` you are using at backend as well as install `XAMPP` or any other server to run PHP script. If you dont want to install full `XAMPP` you can use portable `XAMPP` which is just copy and paste.
You can right a script which can keep checking after specific intervals, if internet is available then synch database with live server.

Comment: I will also try this. Seems the most easy way to deploy