# Desktop Application with Client Server Architecture That Syncs with Cloud Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a web app running with PHP and MySQL.

I need to develop a desktop application which will sync data from the cloud DB whenever the client's computer connects to internet. If the client's computer is not connected to the internet, the desktop application will continue to work offline, using the local DB. The local DB is obviously a replica of the cloud DB.

I don't want to use Microsoft c# to create the desktop application. The desktop application needs to be cross platform and should run on Windows, Mac and Linux.

I have used XAMPP to create a local MySQL DB and have achieved the local app to sync with the cloud app. However, there are multiple problems to that approach.

-- Whenever my client's need to install the local app, they need to call me and I have to install XAMPP in their computer, setup the server, setup the local database and prepare it to sync with the cloud database with their account. They obviously aren't tech savvy so they don't know how to do it themselves.

-- If the client formats his computer, they will call me again and again and I have to set it up for them all the time, which isn't scalable in the longer haul.

-- XAMPP doesn't work when there are other processes running and using common ports. Example - Skype, Quickheal and other antivirus software running will prevent the SQL server to start. Sometimes what happens is that even after I have installed the local app, the client will install an antivirus software or some other tool and my local app will stop working on their computer.

Hence, I need to do away with XAMPP and switch to something else.

SQLite is out of question since it is serverless. I don't want to use .NET either. What I am looking for is this

I want to develop the database driven local application and package it somehow. I want to provider an installer file which will automatically install the database server, setup the database and everything else. The client will only login to the system in the local app and he doesn't have to setup any server. All the work that he does will be synced with the cloud server whenever internet connection resumes.

Please note that there is a master slave work involved. The client will have multiple terminal computers using the master system from other terminals and all these terminal computers will use the local database installed in the master computer.

I have tried to illustrate this with a diagram below

[image]

What's the best way to go about it?

Comment: Things like `xampp` are _development_ utilities, they are not mean at all to be integrated into products or applications. You want to implement an application that is able to a) use an embedded database engine. Take a look at `sqlite3`, maybe that is sufficient and you don't have to install a full fledged database server locally.

Comment: For the cross platform approach: is that a GUI application you want to implement or some background utility? You won't be able to achieve a cross platform utility that really integrates into different graphical user environments, since the differences are too big, the optics too different. If you want to create something that can at least be used everywhere, then take a look at the `qt` toolkit. It is great for that task. Certainly `c++` is the language of choice for `qt` desktop applications for its unrivaled performance, but `qt` bindings exist for many other languages.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes it is a GUI application and not a background utility. Sqlite 3 is serverless --> SQLite is not directly comparable to client/server SQL database engines such as MySQL

Comment: Indeed `sqlite` does not offer a server feature by itself. Question is if you need that... If this is _only_ about that abstract master slave setup you mention, then maybe you can implement a simple request router on top of it. That would still prevent you having to install a full fledged database server. But I don't really understand why you need a database server at all. In your drawing all "slaves" directly communicate with the database. How is that a master slave setup then? Why don't the slaves communicate with the master instead which manages the database?

Comment: The same hint applies to the database syncing you mention... A database server by itself is not able to sync itself. You need additional logic for that and I doubt you want to setup a full database replication "just" for some desktop application. Why doesn't the master offer that syncing capability?

Comment: Imagine a School using my web application. The master machine is in the principal's room which contains the Database which all teachers use in their class. Every classroom has a computer but they don't have the database in their computer, they all have the local app in their computer. THat app pulls all the data from the principal's computer which contains both app and the DB.

Comment: Sure, and how does that speak against the clients in the class rooms communicating with the master at the head masters office instead of directly with the database server? Apart from the fact that one does not want such central logic on a desktop computer at all... What if the head masters computer is switched off? What if the head master does not want to open his computer to the whole school, maybe he has some reason for that? Hm?

Comment: You could use the windows scheduler on the main machine to update the database or use a VM and a scheduler in it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33973340/how-do-i-convert-a-php-web-application-into-a-desktop-application-and-retain-dat?rq=1). With a vm you could save the state and use it on other computers.

Comment: @arkascha the head master's computer is always ON and all the computer's are always connected to a Local network or Wifi.

Comment: If all computers are always connected, then why do you need an offline feature? And even if the head masters system is always on, still only an extremely careless or completely irresponsible head master will allow access to his system! Much better to install a simple headless machine acting as application and database server. Some system that sits somewhere in the cellar and servers only that specific purpose. Often a RaspberryPi will be enough for such task, but today's schools usually have some small sort of a datacenter for such purpose.

Comment: The offline feature is needed because internet connection drops all the time and the teachers cannot rely on the internet for the schools productivity. So what happens is that all the students and the teachers will have the local app installed in their machine which uses the same DB kept in a computer at the principal's room. All the computers are connected to the network via LAN or Wi-Fi but the internet comes and goes. When the internet comes, data is synced to the cloud account. When the internet is not there, everyone keeps working on the desktop app.